# Generic Queue, Method to find minimum value

Tags: java

I am implementing a Generic Queue using Linked list. I have the following methods: enqueue, dequeue and peek. I need help with writing a method that will find the minimum value in the queue and throw an exception if the queue is empty.

The code I have so far is:

```
class Queue <T>  
{
  private Node front, rear; //begin and end nodes
  private int size; // number of items

  //nested class to define node
  private class Node
  { 
    T item;
    Node next;
  }

  //Zero argument constructor
  public Queue()
  {
    front = null;
    rear = null;
    size = 0;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty()
  {
    return (size == 0);
  }

  //peek method
  public T peek(){


      T item = front.item;
      return item;
  }

  //Remove item from the beginning of the list.
  public T dequeue()
  {
    T item = front.item;
    front = front.next;
    if (isEmpty()) 
    {
      rear = null;
    }
    size--;
    return item;
  }

  //Add T to the end of the list.
  public void enqueue(T item)
  {
    Node oldRear = rear;
    rear = new Node();
    rear.item = item;
    rear.next = null;
    if (isEmpty()) 
    {
      front = rear;
    }
    else 
    {
      oldRear.next = rear;
    }
    size++;
  }

  public int size()
  {
    return size;
  }
//finds the maximum and minimum in the list
//assumes that head pointer is defined elsewhere

  public static void main (String a[])
  {
    Queue <Integer> q = new Queue<Integer>();
    q.enqueue(20);
    q.enqueue(30);
    q.enqueue(40);
    q.enqueue(50);
    q.enqueue(60);
    q.enqueue(70);


    System.out.println("Delete an item from queue: " + q.dequeue());    
    System.out.println("Size of the queue: " + q.size());
    System.out.println("Size of the queue: " + q.peek());

  }

}
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace and mark the line where it is thrown

Comment: What is your question? _I need help_ is not specific. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The below method should find the min value and an exception if Queue is empty
I am throwing a custom "QueueEmptyException"

```
public Integer findMin(Queue q){
   if ( q.size == 0 )
      throw new QueueEmptyException();

Integer min = q.front.item;
While (q.front.next != null) {
     if ( min > q.front.next.item ) {
         min = q.front.next.item
         q.front = q.front.next;
     }
return min;
```